# How do I assign a variable to a value in a child node from a Firebase Snapshot?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to minimize the amount of data requests I make to Firebase. I have a snapshot that pulls the following data:

```
snap (Hole1) {
GreenBackX = "40.196339";
GreenBackY = "-105.07354";
GreenCenterX = "40.196336";
GreenCenterY = "-105.073409";
GreenFrontX = "40.196342";
GreenFrontY = "-105.073283";
Hazard1 =     {
    CarryX = "40.196839";
    CarryY = "-105.07104";
    FrontX = "40.196893";
    FrontY = "-105.070626";
    Name = "R Fwy Bunker";
};
Hazard2 =     {
    CarryX = "40.196321";
    CarryY = "-105.071922";
    FrontX = "40.196383";
    FrontY = "-105.071573";
    Name = "L Fwy Bunker";
};
Hazard3 =     {
    CarryX = "40.196622";
    CarryY = "-105.072935";
    FrontX = "40.196662";
    FrontY = "-105.072554";
    Name = "R Fwy Bunker 2";
};
Hazard4 =     {
    CarryX = "40.196176";
    CarryY = "-105.073545";
    FrontX = "40.196225";
    FrontY = "-105.073167";
    Name = "L Greenside Bunker";
};
HoleH = "258.74";
HoleX = "40.19664";
HoleY = "-105.070484";
}
```

What I am aiming to do is assign a variable that would be             `Hazard1\Name`. So far, I've only seen working examples in the docs showing how to grab the initial value, which I do like this: `let holeX = value?["HoleX"] as? Double ?? 0`, but I can't seem to find anything that gets me to the '2nd level' if you will.

There was one example that seemed to say you could do it by referencing it this way: `let hazard1Name = value?["Hazard1/Name"]` but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FIRDataSnapshot` contains data from a given Firebase Database location. The data has *already* been downloaded so there isn't much room for optimizations there, sorry :-(

I think what you might be looking for is:

```
let ref: FIRDatabaseReference = ...
ref.child("Hazard1").child("Name").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
    (snapshot) in
    let name = snapshot.value as! String
    print("Name: \(name)")
}
```

Otherwise, if you *just* want to get your data out of the aforementioned snapshot, try this instead:

```
let snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot = ...
let data = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
let hazard1 = data["Hazard1"] as! [String: Any]
let name = hazard1["Name"] as! String
```

Comment: Thank you @Paulo! the 2nd is what I was looking for.